# How can I etch a perfectly straight line into a sculpted model?

Tags: mirror

How can I etch a perfectly straight line into a sculpted model? I sculpt heads for ventriloquist dummies. I want to etch straight and parallel slot lines on either side of the mouth. Thank you.

Comment: You might want to try using booleans, just create some cube objects in the right spots and add a boolean modifier to the head and select the cube as the carver.

Comment: Hello, please post a picture of the expected result and the starting mesh

Answer (score 3):

you can also use: crease + space with stabilize strokes in sculpt mode or strokes lines

[image]

[image]